# Default SVG style

Tags: css, svg, specifications

What is the default **SVG** style ? for example, what is the default **font** of a new SVG document ? Is it described in the SVG spec ?

```
<svg><text x="10" y="10">Hello</text></svg>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Go here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html) and scan the page for the string "Initial:". Then you find any initial values the spec defines for text rendering. For font-family it states however:

```
'font-family'
    Value:      [[ <family-name> |
                    <generic-family> ],]* [<family-name> |
                    <generic-family>] | inherit
    Initial:    depends on user agent
    Applies to:     text content elements
    Inherited:      yes
    Percentages:    N/A
    Media:      visual
    Animatable:     yes
```

That means, the user agent may decide, which font family to use, if none is given, or if it cannot access a font with the given name.

Overall initial values: The spec defines initial values in every case, where you can write an attribute as CSS declaration (like `fill: red;`). In this case the behaviour is like the one [CSS defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/about.html#initial-value).

In some of the other cases there are fallbacks defined, but it depends on the case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've not tested it myself but according to [SVG Specs 1.1 Font Description](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html#FontDescriptions), there's no default font (font-face/font-family) mentioned. It does stated this:
*"The 'font-face' element corresponds directly to the  @font-face facility in CSS2"*

Well, I would assume it should take the parent container's font if specified. If there's none specified on the parent or no parent, I guess it'll be the browser's default font or the viewer's. Don't quote me though. :P